# How to compare two lists by filtering and sorting "repeated" values

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, nested-lists

I have the following act2.txt file for an email campaign:

```
2021-04-02//email@example.com//Enhance your presentation skills in 15 minutes//Open
2021-04-11//email@example.com//Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR//Open
2021-04-11//email@example.com//Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR//Delivered
2021-04-11//email@example.com//Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR//Delivered
2021-04-11//email@example.com//Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR//Delivered
2021-04-16//email@example.com//YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT//Delivered
2021-04-01//email@example.com//Enhance your presentation skills in 15 minutes//Delivered
2021-04-09//email@example.com//we are here to help you improve your skills//Delivered
2021-04-12//email@example.com//(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar//Delivered
2021-04-13//email@example.com//YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT//Delivered
```

I want to track email activity by customer - I calculated delivered emails, sent emails then open rate.

I generated two lists, one for delivered emails and another for the opened emails:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

#read the file with activities separated by //
afile = "act2.txt"
afile_read = open(afile,"r")
lines = afile_read.readlines()

activityList = []
for activities in lines:
            activity = activities.split("//")
            date = activity[0]
            customer_email = activity[1]
            email_title = activity[2]
            action = activity[3]
            stripped_line = [s.rstrip() for s in activity]
            activityList.append(stripped_line)

#print (activityList)


stripped_email = 'email@example.com'
email_actions = [x for x in activityList if stripped_email in x[1]]
delivered = [x for x in email_actions if 'Delivered' in x]
Opened = [x for x in email_actions if 'Open' in x]
delcount = (len(delivered))
opencount = (len(Opened))
try:
  Open_rate =  opencount / delcount * 100
except ZeroDivisionError:
  Open_rate = 0
print (stripped_email,",", delcount,",", opencount,",", Open_rate,"%")

pprint(delivered)
pprint (Opened)
```

Delivered list:

```
[['2021-04-11',
  'email@example.com',
  'Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR',
  'Delivered'],
 ['2021-04-11',
  'email@example.com',
  'Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR',
  'Delivered'],
 ['2021-04-11',
  'email@example.com',
  'Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR',
  'Delivered'],
 ['2021-04-16',
  'email@example.com',
  'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT',
  'Delivered'],
 ['2021-04-01',
  'email@example.com',
  'Enhance your presentation skills in 15 minutes',
  'Delivered'],
 ['2021-04-09',
  'email@example.com',
  'we are here to help you improve your skills',
  'Delivered'],
 ['2021-04-12',
  'email@example.com',
  '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar',
  'Delivered'],
 ['2021-04-13',
  'email@example.com',
  'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT',
  'Delivered']]
```

Opened list:

```
[['2021-04-02',
  'email@example.com',
  'Enhance your presentation skills in 15 minutes',
  'Open'],
 ['2021-04-11',
  'email@example.com',
  'Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR',
  'Open']]
```

I want to compare both lists and generate a third one (combined activity), filtered by the email subject - if the subject is in delivered list and opened list then it will be counted as a one activity. However, **email subject could be repeated** like the email was delivered 3 times but it was opened only once. I cannot find the proper logic to to that as I am still learning python.

**EDIT for more clarity:**

If an email is found in open list filtered by title, then the same title should be removed from the delivered list by last date and a new list is generated with combined activities.

Comment: Since you want them sorted anyway, I'm going to point you [to `itertools.groupby`; read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), it's basically the canonical way to dedupe already sorted inputs. [`heapq.merge` may be useful as well](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge), if you're processing/sorting the opened and delivered inputs separately, then want to merge the sorted results together.

Comment: I don't quite understand what is the desired output you want from these two lists.

Comment: Hi @BoobyTrap basically, if an email is found in opened list with the same title - then it will be removed from the delivered list items and generate a combined list for all (delivered and opened).

Comment: The output you want is the combination of delivered and opened? If so, to make things simple, you can use dictionary with key is title. But I doubt that all opened items are in delivered list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think of this in a different way, you are not combining lists.

If an email was opened, that means it was also received. This means that your opened list is also your combined list.

After you realize that, all you have to do is copy the unopened emails to a result list for emails that ere not opened.

Go over the opened emails list and copy the subjects into a set, after that go over the received emails and check if the subject is in the set, if it is then do nothing. If the subject isn't in the set then copy it to unopened emails list.

It is a very simple piece of code:

```
opened_subjects = set()
unopened = []
for email in opened:
    opened_subjects.add(email[2])

unopened_subjects = set()
for email in received:
    if all(email[2] not in subj_set 
           for subj_set in (opened_subjects, unopened_subjects)):
        unopened.append(email)
        unopened_subjects.add(email[2])

print('Both received and opened:', opened)
print('Unopened emails:', unopened)
```

A small note -
The reason for the each of the sets is different. The first set `opened_subjects` is there because of the `set`'s ability to contain only unique items, and that is what is required in this case. The second set `unopened_subjects` is there because it is faster to check if an item is in a set than in a list, seeing as I am checking before adding to the set any way then there is no requirement for the set ability to store unique only.

Comment: thank you this solved 80% of my problem. If email[2] is a repeated title so I need to rely on the count of total delivered by title and subtract the same opened title from the total. Again I am not able to produce the logic of counting email titles per list.

Comment: @Mtaly You can use another set to keep track of your unopened. I'll update the answer.

Comment: thank you for giving ideas and clarifying things. I also generated the difference between delivered and opened by converting lists into dictionaries and use the library `dictdiffer`