# How to substract python dictionaries with counters & filtered values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following collections counters:

**counter1:**

```
Counter({('2021-04-11', 'email@example.com', 'Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR', 'Delivered'): 2,
         ('2021-04-25', 'email@example.com', 'Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR', 'Delivered'): 1,
         ('2021-04-16', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered'): 1,
         ('2021-04-01', 'email@example.com', 'Enhance your presentation skills in 15 minutes', 'Delivered'): 1,
         ('2021-04-09', 'email@example.com', 'we are here to help you improve your skills', 'Delivered'): 1,
         ('2021-04-12', 'email@example.com', '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', 'Delivered'): 1,
         ('2021-04-13', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered'): 1})
```

**counter2:**

```
Counter({('2021-04-02', 'email@example.com', 'Enhance your presentation skills in 15 minutes', 'Open'): 1,
         ('2021-04-11', 'email@example.com', 'Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR', 'Open'): 1})
```

I need to subtract dict1 - dict2 based on email_titles

I tried:

```
pprint (dict1.subtract(dict2))
```

To get the following output:

```
Counter({('2021-04-11', 'email@example.com', 'Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR', 'Delivered'): 1,
         ('2021-04-25', 'email@example.com', 'Enroll in the presentations skills - FREE WEBINAR', 'Delivered'): 1,
         ('2021-04-16', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered'): 1,
         ('2021-04-09', 'email@example.com', 'we are here to help you improve your skills', 'Delivered'): 1,
         ('2021-04-12', 'email@example.com', '(1st meeting) here is our recorded presentation skills webinar', 'Delivered'): 1,
         ('2021-04-13', 'email@example.com', 'YOU ARE INVITED TO THIS PROGRAMMING EVENT', 'Delivered'): 1})
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You have `collections.Counter` not dict, do you want to keep this as a counter object or is your input a `dict`?

Comment: Hi @PacketLoss my two inputs are lists and I converted then into collections.Counter to able to subtract counts.

The idea behind this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527112/how-to-compare-two-lists-by-filtering-and-sorting-repeated-values

Comment: What is your end goal from your original data set?

Comment: Track delivered and opened email per customer. The issue is the repetition of emails titles between lists. so I my idea is to convert the delivered list  titles into numbers and subtract the opened list with the same title.